# dropdown menu when i click in a link

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have more or less the same problem like in the post "Bootstrap 3 - Disapear the dropdown menu when i click in a link", but I couldn't close the drop-down submenus and the function is in this post, it doesn't work me properly.

I want that when I click on a submenu this dropdown and when I click on another submenu which is open is closed and I click open, now all submenus not closed, only when you click again in this submenu no when click en the other submenu:

[image: first submenu displayed] [image: second submenu displayed]

HTML is too similar to the one published in this post:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#MainMenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu" class="dropdown-toggle"><img src="img/ico_menu_off.png" /></a>
        <div id="MainMenu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="list-group panel dropdown">
                <a href="#link1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Links to Portals <i class="caret"></i></a>
                <div id="link1" class="collapse background-submenu">
                    <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Portal 1 </a>
                    <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Portal 2 </a>
                    <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Portal 3 </a>
                    <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Portal 4 </a>
                </div>
                <a href="#link2" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Links to Calculators <i class="caret"></i></a>
                <div id="link2" class="collapse background-submenu"></div>
                <a href="#link3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Links to Tools <i class="caret"></i></a>
                <div id="link3" class="collapse background-submenu">
                    <a href="#SubMenu3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu3">Customer Credit OverView</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a id="btn-customersearch" ng-click="customerSearchClick();" href="#customerSearch"><img src="img/u2973_off.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a id="btn-customerhome" ng-click="homeClick();" href="#/"><img src="img/u2983_on.png" /></a></li>       
</ul>     

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="navbar-manager">Sheldon Cooper</li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/u2977.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/u2975.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/u2979.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/ico_closesession.png" /></a></li>
</ul>          
</div>
```

But and I've got the following functions:

```
//Hide the menu when you click everywhere on the page - Ocultar menu cuando se haga click fuera del mismo
        $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        //$(document).on("click", "body", function(e) {
            //Target => collapse('hide')
           if($("#MainMenu").hasClass('in')) {
               $("#MainMenu").collapse("hide");
           }
           //stop the code from bubbling up
           e.stopPropagation();
           e.preventDefault();     
        });
    //dropdown menu
        $(document).on("click", function() {
            $("#MainMenu>div>a").on('click', function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            var dest = $(this).attr('href');
            $(dest).collapse('toggle');
         });
        });
```

how I can do that when I drop-down a submenu hide a submenu which is open?

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/deulX.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV7c5.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/TACqp.png

Comment: I see no problems with your code. Here is a codepen. If you can use this to reproduce the error, I'll be able to help you out better. http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/mVWxXK

Comment: the menu displays fine, but when one submenu is open and I click on another submenu, which is open should be closed and not closed.
For example, I have opened in submenu "Link to portals" and I click on "Link to Tools", the submenu "Link to portals" should be closed and not closed. I don't know if I explained well, because my english in not very good, sorry.

Comment: I would like the menu had the accordion effect

Comment: Give me a few minutes. I was in a meeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood your problem correctly, you want one submenu to close when second sub menu is clicked(or when it is open). Change your Js to this:

```
//Hide the menu when you click everywhere on the page - Ocultar menu cuando se haga click fuera del mismo
       $(document).on('click', function(e) {
       //$(document).on("click", "body", function(e) {
           //Target => collapse('hide')
          if ($("#MainMenu").hasClass('in')) {
             $("#MainMenu").collapse("hide");
          }
         //stop the code from bubbling up
         e.stopPropagation();
         e.preventDefault();
      });

     //dropdown menu
     $(document).on("click", function() {
        $("#MainMenu>div>a").on('click', function(e) {
           e.stopPropagation();
           var dest = $(this).attr('href');
           $(dest).collapse('toggle');

           if ($('#MainMenu>div>a').not(this) && $('#MainMenu>div>a').next('div.in')) {
              $("#MainMenu>div>a").next('div').removeClass('in');
           }
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this script below:

```
            // Collapse accordion every time dropdown is shown
        $('.dropdown-accordion').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (event) {
          var accordion = $(this).find($(this).data('accordion'));
          accordion.find('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
        });

        // Prevent dropdown to be closed when we click on an accordion link
        $('.dropdown-accordion').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="collapse"]', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          $($(this).data('parent')).find('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
          $($(this).attr('href')).collapse('show');
        })
```

and this CSS

```
        .panel-default>.panel-heading {
            box-shadow: none;
        }

        .fake-panel-link{
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #333;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }

        .fake-panel-link a, .panel-body  a {
            color:inherit;
        }

        .panel-body {
            background-color: #40B369;
            color:#333;
        }
```

All you have to do is simply nest an accordion in your dropdown. Same thought process you originally had.

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/mVWxXK)

The functionality works, all you have to do is some CSS beautification and you are on your way